# How to extract random IDs values for elements with jmeter in a jsf web app

Tags: testing, jsf, jmeter

The application is made with JSF. I recorded the script with JMeter proxy, it works well, but the number in the id for some fields change after a day, so I need to find a way to extract and pass the correct one. 
I don't know well how to use Regex, so I will really appreciate any help. 
Thank you.

Parameters and values that I need to generate random [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dxVm.png)

This is the div in the HTML with the id I need to generate random [Div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vn2jX.png)

```
<div id="solicitudSteps:j_idt75" class="ui-wizard ui-widget" style="width: 100%;">
```

**EDIT**

This is the [Css Selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gHS7.png) I'm using

This is what returns when I test with the [Css Selector Tester](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUGZn.png)

Comment: Just assign it an exlipicit id in the source. And code should be in text, not images

Comment: I think you haven't developed this application. In ideal world, you should ping the application back to the responsible JSF developer and tell him/her to install the http://showcase.omnifaces.org/viewhandlers/NoAutoGeneratedIdViewHandler

Comment: Hi Kukeltje, I'm not the dev, I'm making the script.

Comment: Then ask the dev to do that or use an xpath selector or css selector or ...

Comment: And don't post images of 'code' post it inline...

Comment: Answers should be in answers and not as an edit of the question. I reverted this edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like these dynamic values are coming from the previous response as [hidden inputs](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp) so it is the matter of [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start), you can extract these dynamic input names along with the values using i.e. [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) as

1. Add CSS Selector Extractor as a child of the previous request and configure it to extract hiddens input names

   [image]
2. Add one more CSS Selector Extractor to get hidden inputs values:

   [image]
3. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the request where you need to provide dynamic inputs and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   1.upto(vars.get('hiddenInputName_matchNr') as int, { index ->
       sampler.addArgument(vars.get('hiddenInputName_' + index), vars.get('hiddenInputValue_' + index))
   })
   ```

   So the overall test plan structure would look like:

   [image]
4. That's it, JMeter should extract all the dynamic inputs from the previous response and add them to the current request automatically.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, is not an input is a div, I tried this in the Css Selector Tester: Selector: div[class=ui-wizard ui-widget]  but it returns Match = 0. I will add the images in the post.

Comment: I used JODD as the CSS selector extractor implementation and worked. Thank you :D

Comment: @AnaGallardo: If this answer helped, mark it as such: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers